# Java tree with columns

Tags: java, swing, jtree, multiple-columns

I have a task to create java tree, with three columns: Sport name, Count of sports which are in sport category, and last update. Something similar is dispayed on image bellow:

[image: Design of JTree]

As you can see, there are 4 kinds of sports: Water, Ball, Skying, Dancing. When I expand skying, there are 3 sports of its kind.

But how to make columns. I can make JTree with nodes and stuff, but how to add columns?

Comment: So, you've asked a question about `JTree` and `JTable`, but are using `Tree` and `Table` (from SWT I assume?) - I think you need to re-tag you're question.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTTreeWithMulticolumns.htm) is a good example for using a `Tree` with multiple columns. It looks like this:

[image]

I would however suggest using a JFace [`TreeViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FTreeViewer.html). There are good tutorials [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/TreeViewerArticle.htm) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTree/article.html).

Comment: I have to do this with Swing components!

Comment: @Mr.M Well, then you should have tagged it correctly _before_ I gave my answer, not change the tags after I gave my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a view that *expands* like a tree but has *rows & columns* like a table. Consider [`Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html), cited [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).

[image]